# How to use on_message together with client.command?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

```
    @client.event
    async def on_message(message):
        await client.process_commands(message)
```

I have no idea how to use this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above code is totally fine. If you haven't DEFINED Your bot yet, You have to do it.
Here is the simple code you can modify according to your needs.

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = 'YOUR PREFIX')
@bot.command()
async def ling(ctx):
    await ctx.send("Mabel")
```

Comment: Actually, I've already done that, still doesn't work. :<

Comment: Do you use any on_message event? If yes, You have to add bot.process_commands(message) in the event. If that's not the case, It's either your bot doesn't have the permissions to reply in the channel or the Token you have generated by Oauth is wrong. Let me know if anything helps you out.

Comment: Ohhh, so the on_message event was the culprit? Thank you so much for your help <3 Just one last thing, can you show me exactly how I'm supposed to add the bot.process_commands(message) line?

Comment: @bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    

bot.process_commands(message)

Comment: Thank you so much, you've been a great help :D